# How to displayJson Object Name/Label while returning the list of the same object type

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Here are  my Class

```
[DataContract(Name="Test")]
public class Test
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }    
  [DataMember]
  public string Type { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name="Root")]
public static class Root
{
   [DataMember(Name="TestList")]
   public static List<Test> TestList { get; set; }
}


Expected Json To be returned 
  {
   "Test":[
    {
    "Name": "MyApp",      
    "Type": "web"
    },
    {
    "Name": "MyDatabase",      
    "Type": "db"
    }
     ]
  }

Actual Json Returned 

 [
  {
    "Name": "MyApp",      
    "Type": "web"
  },
  {
    "Name": "MyDatabase",      
    "Type": "db"
  }
]
```

WebApi Method to return the objects

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Test> Get()
    {
        return Root.TestList;
    }
```

The problem i am facing is when i run the above code I see the json data being returned in the "Actual" Format but i would love to see the Json in the "Expected Format" (please see above for the formats). 
The only difference is the label of the array. How can i put this label? 
i looked at tons of json docs but no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is returning a `List<Test>` so that will be serialized as a JSON array.  If you want to see a JSON object with a named array-valued property, you need to return a POCO containing an appropriately named property, such as your `Root`:

```
[HttpGet]
public Root Get()
{
    return Root;
}
```

Also, you need to change the name from `TestList` to `Test`:

```
[DataContract(Name="Root")]
public class Root
{
   [DataMember(Name="Test")] // Changed this
   public List<Test> TestList { get; set; }
}
```

Or, if your `Root` contains other properties you don't want serialized, or in other ways can't be serialized (because it's static), you can always return some generic wrapper, like so:

```
[DataContract]
public class RootWrapper<T>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Test")]
    public T Test { get; set; }
}
```

And then

```
    [HttpGet]
    public RootWrapper<IEnumerable<Test>> Get()
    {
        return new RootWrapper<IEnumerable<Test>> { Test = Root.TestList };
    }
```

Comment: Hi dbc. my apologies as i missed one vital information to be placed there. The root class and the list TestList they are static property. i have updated my post. Yes if those were not static then your answer would have been 100 percent correct

Comment: @Sike12 - OK, how about the `RootWrapper<T>`?